# node js using Mongo and Redis simulteniously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, socket.io

I am developing a little project using Node.js. I am using `mongoose` for models, therefore i am using `MongoDb`. And i keep sessions in `MongoStore`. Also i want to use `socket.io` running several processes of Node. From `socket.io` docs:

```
    The MemoryStore only allows you deploy socket.io on a single process. 
If you want to scale to multiple process and / or multiple servers 
you can use our RedisStore which uses the Redis 
NoSQL database as man in the middle.
```

So i think i need `Redis` too. I am new in Node and i want to know - is it normal to use two databases to manage different parts of application. Or is there a way to work with `socket.io` when running several processes of Node and use only `MongoDb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just recently a solution that uses MongoStore with pub/sub functionality using [mubsub](https://github.com/scttnlsn/mubsub) (Pub/sub for Node.js and MongoDB) has appeared.

It can be attached to socket.io in almost the same way as you would with RedisStore:

```
io.configure(function() {
    io.set('store', new MongoStore({host: 'localhost', port: 27017, db:'session_db'}));
});
```

More information and source at: https://github.com/kof/socket.io-mongo

Comment: On a side note, I didn't manage to get it working with multiple processes running, it kept handshaking. So if you got it working, please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

The Redis store is already built into Socket.IO, but more importantly has 2 important features that are particularly needed for Socket.IO:

1) Publish-subscribe (to communicate between processes) 
2) Key-value store (to store all the info about connections)

While the key-value store part can be done with MongoDB, it doesn't provide the pub-sub functionality.

Bottom line, IF you need to scale beyond one process (meaning you are expecting more than some thousand concurrent request) than RedisStore is the solution.

Resources:

- [Examples in using RedisStore in socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267292/examples-in-using-redisstore-in-socket-io)
- http://www.ranu.com.ar/2011/11/redisstore-and-rooms-with-socketio.html