# socket.io redis ECONNREFUSED

Tags: redis, socket.io

my host has allowed ports 8000 to 8010

```
var express = require('express')
  , https = require('https')
  , app = express()
  , cluster = require('cluster')
  , numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length
  , RedisStore = require("socket.io/lib/stores/redis")
  , redis = require("socket.io/node_modules/redis");
  , pub = redis.createClient(8002)
  , sub = redis.createClient(8002)
  , client = redis.createClient(8002);
  , server = https.createServer(options,app);
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.set('store',new RedisStore({redisPub:pub,redisSub:sub,redisClient:client}));
if(cluster.isMaster){for(var i=0;i<numCPUs;i++){cluster.fork();}}
else{
  console.log(numCPUs);
  io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){/*do stuff*/});
  server.listen(8002);
}
```

I'm having real trouble understanding if I can't connect to redis because of the port or wether the redis supplied with socket.io is turned on...

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:8002 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
at RedisClient.on_error (/home/engine/public_html/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:149:24)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/engine/public_html/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:83:14)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at net.js:426:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
[root@vps ~]#    info  - socket.io started
```

also, I don't understand how this can give me extra workers (I console.log(numCPUs) and it says 1, so does that mean I only have 1 worker? If so, this means that there is no change to performance; making this endeavour pointless!?).

Comment: It's unclear on which port redis is actually listening? You are trying to connect to port 8002, then making your own server listen on that same port. That can't be right.

Comment: i've also tried connecting redis to 8003 and listening with my app on 8002 but I get the same error

Comment: After more careful reading of your comment, I gather you think redis comes with socket.io. It doesn't. You need to install and run redis by itself, first, just like any other database.

Comment: That's the adapter library for socket.io and redis.

Comment: socket.io/lib/stores/redis.js ? socket.io/node_modules/redis ??

Comment: No, again, you need to [download](http://redis.io/download) and install redis first. But honestly, I'm not sure you need it -- perhaps concentrate on building your application, leave out the cluster for now and just use the default MemoryStore?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install and run your own instance of redis and then use the node client to connect.

See this thread to get more information to do what you are trying to do.

[Examples in using RedisStore in socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267292/examples-in-using-redisstore-in-socket-io)