# socket.io-client object is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I opened a question here earlier ([Socket.io trigger events between two node.js apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953338/socket-io-trigger-events-between-two-node-js-apps)), this was much help, but I am confused out of my mind.

I keep getting object is not a function on my client side script.

A little setup, I have a front end site that is served with express `localhost:9200` then I have a back end app `localhost:3100` that is also served with express and I am trying to emit events from `localhost:9200` to the socket.io server `localhost:3100`

**Client script for website localhost:9200**

```
// I have tried many different ways
var socket = io('http://localhost:3100');
var socket = io('http://localhost');
var socket = io();
```

**EDIT**

*The issue was with the above of course, because `io` in the above case for some reason was an object when it should be a function, I came across an old post which mentioned using `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3100');` `connect` and that worked, I though it was depreciated or something, I have no clue why the docs don't mention this but it fixed my issue.*

All result in object is not a function. I include the client side script like this

```
// tried some different ways
<script src="http://localhost:3100/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> // this is a 404
```

I have installed https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-client and on the server for the front end website :9200 I have set it up like.

```
// tried a couple ways to connect
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3100');
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost');
  socket.on('connect', function(){});
  socket.on('event', function(data){});
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
```

I am confused on how to properly configure this so that I can get my site to emit socket events to my server and visa versa?

Comment: I just noticed on my app server :3100 when I boot my front end server I get this message on the app server `info  - unhandled socket.io url` and it repeats itself many times.

Answer (score 5):

Well I figured it out, this is pretty ridiculous but on the client side javascript I needed to add `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3100');` the `io.connect` made it work versus `var socket = io('http://localhost:3100');`

Maybe I missed it but the docs don't say to use `io.connect` https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-client whatever it works and I am happy, any thoughts on why the docs don't mention this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is io.connect is pre 1.0 syntax. They changed it for whatever reason. These are the exact kind of fun surprises I have come to expect in socket.io.

Comment: In Socket.IO 2.0, `io()` and `io.connect()` are exactly the same thing.